# VisualVM stack variable values when doing a thread dump

Tags: java, jvm, visualvm

Is it possible to obtain a view of the values of the stack variables when doing a thread dump in VisualVM? Currently, all that I can see when choosing a thread dump of some jvm process is the stack trace, not the exact variable values in stack frames.

If not, is there a (working) plugin that allows one to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VisualVM 1.3+ shows local variables in the thread dump.

Comment: I could not find them in the thread dump - but they are available in the heap dump - there is a link to the instance tab for each local. Cool, thanks!

Comment: I mean the thread dump, which is displayed in Overview tab in the heap dump.