# VisualVM stack primitive types variable values when doing a thread dump

Tags: java, jvm, visualvm

This question is very similar to [that question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097755/visualvm-stack-variable-values-when-doing-a-thread-dump)

however it is more specific. I would like to dump stack trace also with local variables that are java primitives e.g. int. In other words I would like to see the stack trace in the state it is visible during debugging. Is it possible with VisualVM or other software?

Comment: You can get this information with a debugger.

Comment: I know, but I need to get this info during thread (or another) dump. My JVM gets stuck and I want to see its complete state, both heap and full stack frames.

Comment: I believe only the debugger can do that.  You could try using JVMTI interface to get debug information with a minimal pause to the application.